# Filename randomization for chunks generated for Vue async components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, async-components

I have a laravel app that loads a bunch of vue components and I am loading them asynchronously like

```js
Vue.component("general-info", function (resolve, reject) { 
  require(["./components/general-info.vue"], resolve)
});
```

and so far all is loading properly the only problem I am facing is with browsers cache; all components are being splited in small files like: 0.js 1.js etc
is there any way I can generate them using random file names instead of sequential numbers?

I am using **webpack** to build my app, its a laravel/vue app

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried

```
this.webpackConfig.output = {
        path: Mix.isUsing('hmr') ? '/' : path.resolve(Config.publicPath),
        filename: '[name].js&t=' + new Date().getTime(),
        chunkFilename: '[name].js&t=' + new Date().getTime(),
        publicPath: Mix.isUsing('hmr')
            ? `${http}://${Config.hmrOptions.host}:${
                  Config.hmrOptions.port
              }/`
            : '/'
    };
```

it does build them with a cache busting suffix, but doesn't download them attaching the suffix.

**"Solution"**

As @Michal suggested I changed the webpack config to:

```
filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
chunkFilename:'[name].[chunkhash].js',
```

To make it really fit to my environment I
also changed my scripts in package.json to remove old app.[chunk].js files
like:

```
"watch-poll": "rm public/js/* && cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch......."
```

also same for production....

Now in my blade files, I load the main app script dynamically like:

```
@php
$path = public_path('js');
$files = File::files($path);
$js_file = str_replace(public_path(), '', $files[0]);
@endphp
<script src="{{ $js_file }}"></script>
```

Perhaps is not the best solution but it is working for me.

Comment: Whats your webpack config ?

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? You may need to manage caching there. For instance my deployment pipeline manages the cache-control during every deployment to S3/CloudFront

Comment: Also, what version of vue cli are you using? My production build is already fingerprinting the chunks. Example in dev I may have 1.js, But in the production build it will be something like chunk-ceaf8c24.f9cf1da0.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
```

[Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames)

Using `contenthash` is better than generating timestamp on every build anyway because is allows caching of unchanged chunks (components) while ensures browser re-downloads changed ones...

Comment: That did it! Just now I have a problem with the include in the main index.html file as it includes it as app.js and actually it is not the latest built version. Can manipulate it of course just is there anyway I can prevent the contenthash on the app.js file... as mostly the problem now is with npm run watch-poll while in development, changes do not reflect unless I change the html files that do include it...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but in most Vue environments, `index.html` is generated automatically from a template using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) which automatically includes all js chunks with correct names

Comment: You can also try to experiment with different name templates for `filename` (which is for "entry" file chunk) and `chunkFilename` (which is used for "name of non-entry chunk files"). Anyway having static name for any chunk is recipe for a disaster in the future (caching issues)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I have a "solution" somehow.